# Why Fourier transform owns two different signs?

Tags: fourier-analysis

In my book, the defination of Fourier transform is $$F(\lambda)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{i\lambda t}dt$$
While the reverse one is: $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F(\lambda)e^{-i\lambda t}dt$$
But in other place (here as well), I always encounter another "just on the contrary" system like: $$F(\lambda)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{-i\lambda t}dt$$
You can see that the sign of exponential part is changed.

Why will this happen?

Comment: This is just a matter of different people making different conventions —a fact of life. You'll also find different normalization coefficients used in both; for example, using $(2\pi)^{-1/2}$ i both the transform and its inverse is much more symmetrical and more useful for some purposes. Other people prefer to stick a $2\pi$ in the exponent of the exponential, too.

Comment: The existence of "The Fourier Transform" is naught but a beautiful lie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't consider the inverse transformation it is unimportant whether you write $e^{i\lambda t}$ or $e^{-i\lambda t}$ in the definition of $F$.

As soon as you look at $F$ and $F^{-1}$ at the same time you have to put a minus sign either in the definition of $F$ or in the resulting $F^{-1}$. This is so because the Fourier transform is sort of a "$90^\circ$ rotation, or multiplication by $i$, in function space", and $(i)\cdot(i)\ne 1$, but $(i)\cdot(-i)=1$.

Comment: Indeed, if you apply the Fourier transform 4 times you get the original function back.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I also faced as a student.  This happens everywhere in mathematics and perhaps in other subjects too.  It is better to use different names when you have a different meaning or a different formula.  It is better to use one standard than every one use their own formula and use the same name.

Matrix canonical forms also different mathematicians use slightly different forms.  When a student reads both the forms, he is not sure which one to use in the exam.

In abstract algebra too, groups and rings and their properties are slightly different from different authors.